# How do I find the turtle shell name error

Tags: python, nameerror, python-turtle

I am new to programing and I'm going through a book called Coding Projects In Python. I am getting an undefined name error in my code. I have searched through my code and cannot find it, I'm not sure exactly where the error is in my code. The code is up until step 10 from page 161 to 164 in the book.

```
import random
import turtle as t

t.bgcolor('yellow')

caterpillar = t.Turtle()
caterpillar.shape('square')
caterpillar.speed(0)
caterpillar.penup()
caterpillar.hideturtle()

leaf = t.Turtle()
leaf_shape = ((0, 0), (14, 2), (18, 6), (20, 20), \
              (6, 18), (2, 14))
t.register_shape('leaf', leaf_shape)
leaf.shape('leaf')
leaf.color('green')
leaf.penup()
leaf.hideturtle()
leaf.speed(0)

game_started = False
text_turtle = t.Turtle()
text_turtle.write('Press SPACE to start', align='center',\
                  font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
text_turtle.hideturtle()


score_turtle = t.Turtle()
score_turtle.hideturtle()
score_turtle.speed(0)

def outside_window():
    pass


def game_over():
    pass


def display_score(current_score):
    pass


def place_leaf():
    pass


def start_game():
    global game_started
    if game_started:
        return
    game_started = True


    score = 0
    text_turtle.clear()

    caterpillar_speed = 2
    caterpillar_length = 3
    caterpillar.shapesize(1, caterpillar_length, 1)
    caterpillar.showturtle()
    display_score(score)
    place_leaf()


while True:
    caterpillar.forward(caterpillar_speed)
    if caterpillar.distance(leaf) < 20:
        place_leaf()
        caterpillar_length = caterpillar_length + 1
        caterpillar.shapesize(1, caterpillar_length, 1)
        caterpillar_speed = caterpillar_speed + 1
        score = score + 10
        display_score(score)
    if outside_window():
        game_over()
        break


t.onkey(start_game, 'space')
t.listen()
t.mainloop()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\caterpillar.py", line 68, in <module>
    caterpillar.forward(caterpillar_speed)
NameError: name 'caterpillar_speed' is not defined
```

Comment: The `while True:` loop needs to be indented so it's inside `start_game()`

Comment: I tried using that tip but it seemed to still not work. I even re-wrote the code but I still got the error.. Is there something else I can do to fix this? Also, is there a specific editor that I can use to identify the problem easier? I tried indenting it several different ways but they did not seem to work.

Comment: If you put the while loop inside the function, it should be able to access the variable. You must have done something else wrong.

Comment: Note that adding to `caterpillar_speed` won't change `caterpillar.speed`. Are you sure you need both variables?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yes I've tried it again and it was a formatting issue thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just to see what was going on, I copied your code into IDLE and noticed that while you did a good job adding `global` to some variables in functions, you seemed to overlook some other variables inside the function `start_game()`. I added `global` to a few variables, so your code ended up looking like this:

```
def start_game():
    global game_started
    if game_started:
        return
    game_started = True

    global score
    score = 0
    text_turtle.clear()

    global caterpillar_speed
    global caterpillar_length
    caterpillar_speed = 2
    caterpillar_length = 3
    caterpillar.shapesize(1, caterpillar_length, 1)
    caterpillar.showturtle()
    display_score(score)
    place_leaf()
```

Just remember, you need to put `global` in front of any variable you defined inside a function that you want to use outside of it later. When you tried to use the variable `caterpillar_speed` outside of the function `start_game()`, the main body of the program couldn't access the function to see what the variable was. Using `global` as you did for the variable `game_started`, for instance, made `game_started` usable both inside and outside the function.

Happy programming and I hope this answer helps! P.S. Your game looks awesome!